# how to make a group using the numeric data (stata)

Tags: regression, stata

i'm trying to make a regression model through the stata.

so far, i want to know that is there a difference in wages based on educational level(masters vs undergrat)

howver, my DTA file have a lot of label lists,

for example
70 Post Grad, M.A/M.S.xxxx

71 Post Grad, Prof. xxxxTraining/Fine & Applied Arts Prog

72 Post Grad, Diploma/Masteral/Doctorate xxxx

73 Post Grad, Prof. Dip./Cert./Masteral./Doct.xxxxx

74 Post Grad, Cert./Dip./M.S./PhD. xxxxx

75 Post Grad, Dip./M.S./PhD.xxxx

76 Post Grad, Dip./M.S./PhD. IN xxxx

78 Post Grad, Dip./M.A./PhD. xxxxxxx

aduate

i want to combine all of post grad lists(70 to 78). how can I do? using the stata? THanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about you create a dummy?

```
gen f_master=0
forval x=70/78 {
replace f_master=1 if variable==`x'
}
```

EDIT: substitute "variable" in the code with the name of your variable identifying the numbers 70,71,..

Comment: change "variable" in the code with your own name of the variable

Comment: thanks i made it then how can i apply to make a regression? just "regress wages f_master "..  wages = dependent , z2041_h_educ is my independent variable).

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner I would use **recode** as the easiest way to get started.

For the indicator (dummy) variable I would not do what @Giacomo did, instead would type

```
gen byte fmaster = inrange(variable, 70, 78) if variable < .
```

Comment: thanks. i'm doing master's ,,, however, stata is my first time.. in my life.. yes I'm a beginner..

Comment: @purugin Although you got some answers, code-specific questions like this are off-topic on CV and will usually be closed. Nor is Stack Overflow a good forum for beginner questions. Statalist would be better for you, but read its help first http://www.statalist.org/forums/help first. In essence, every forum expects you to try to read the software documentation first. Beginners too!